# Fitting interjection for "that's nothing"

Tags: interjections

What would be an appropriate interjection to express little bit of disdain, like

> - I made it in 30 minutes.
> - Aaah, that's nothing, my friend did it in 15.

Is there something more fitting than "aaah"?

Comment: Well, there's always "whoopie shit".

Comment: In the meantime, [I found](https://spanish.yourdictionary.com/pche-interjection-interjection) also  *Bah!*, possible? And is *Pche!* possible in English?

Comment: A veritable goldmine of interjections: https://www.dailywritingtips.com/100-mostly-small-but-expressive-interjections/

Comment: @Tomas *Bah!* does not work here, it might if the situation were reversed: "My friend made in in 15." then "Bah! It took me 30."

Comment: @WeatherVane so *Bah* is more like admiration? Ok, and what about *Pche!* Would it work in my context?

Comment: No, but my example was reversed. It's the person who did badly, or was disappointed, who says "bah!"

Comment: 1) and does he say "bah!" more out of admiration to the first person, or out of disappointment over himself? 2) And what about "Pche!", would it fit the context of my question? Thanks!

Comment: No, you don't say "bah" out of admiration. I have never heard of "pche". Is that a variant of "pshaw" or "pfft"?

Comment: @WeatherVane If your comments are defective, please delete them; it makes the train of thought difficult to follow. Mark the other comments "no longer needed" , please

Comment: @Cascabel which comment is defective?

Comment: @WeatherVane "No, but my example was reversed. It's the person who did badly, or was disappointed, who says "bah!" " It's confusing.

Comment: @Cascabel there was nothing defective. OP misunderstood the use of "bah" and I explained that it would be used in a case which was the other way round.

Comment: Whatever, I'm still watching the _comicios_, so signing off ...

Comment: @Cascabel I agree that it did become rather messy.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think "pche" might be a variant spelling of "pssh"

Comment: "pche" would be working in Czech and I was surprised to find out that [it works also in Spanish](https://spanish.yourdictionary.com/pche-interjection-interjection), so I thought perhaps it might work in English as well :-)

Answer (score 17):

I offer (see [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pfft))

> **pfft**
> <sub>EXCLAMATION</sub>
>
> **1.2** Used to express a contemptuous or dismissive attitude.

So you could remark

> Pfft, that's nothing, my friend did it in 15.

Answer (score 11):

**"So what?"** can be used to express how underwhelmed you are by a particular statement.

**"Big deal"** can be said sarcastically to indicate that the statement is not, in fact, a big deal at all.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like a perfect situation for "**meh**". I've seen it mainly used as an interjection:

> used to express indifference or mild disappointment

([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meh)).

I would say that it expresses "dismisiveness".

Note that you can also use it adjectively:

> not impressive : so-so

([Same Merriam-Webster entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meh)).

In my experience I see "meh" used more on the internet that in face-to-face conversation. On some internet social spaces "meh" seemed to get really popular in the 2010s, and it was common to see a response to a comment that looked like

> Meh. The games for the PS4 are mostly knock-offs, and I .....

Be warned that the person going around saying "meh" to other people's remarks is going to sound like a bit of a jerk, but that seems to fit with the example conversation you've given.

(Personally, I've a adopted a policy of skipping any remarks that are prefaced with "meh", as I've found it too be a pretty reliable indicator of someone who doesn't show much respect for others. I'll be curious to see what other's attitudes towards "meh" are.)

Comment: _looks at t-shirt I'm wearing that says only "meh"_  Sometimes it's just a mood.

Comment: My good friend gave me a travel mug marked with simply: "Meh."  I think it's because I don't tend to get worked up about things that other people get emotional about (and perhaps because it's close in spelling to my online handle).  I don't consider myself disrespectful.

Answer (score 5):

The expressive interjection 'pah' goes to the heart of "disdain":

> **A.** *int.*
>  Expressing disgust or disdain.
>
> *[OED](https://oed.com/)*, pah, *int.* and *adj.*

*OED* puts 'pah' in "Frequency Band 3", which they describe as containing

> words which occur between 0.01 and 0.1 times per million words in typical modern English usage. These words are not commonly found in general text types like novels and newspapers, but at the same [time] they are not overly opaque or obscure.

Answer (score 4):

***p'shaw***

> used to express irritation, disapproval, contempt, or disbelief

[-MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pshaw)

If you like older expressions.

As in...

> I made it in 30 minutes.

> ***P'shaw,*** that's nothing, my friend did it in 15.

Otherwise:

***henh?***..

> a fake laugh, usually used when someone says something obvious and stupid or not funny, or when someone says something over and over again to the point where it becomes stupid...

if you accept [UD](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=henh)

As in:

> I made it in 30 minutes.

> ***Henh***, that's nothing, my friend did it in 15.

Comment: I have never seen either of these. I have probably _heard_ "henh", but never imagined it to be written like that, and reading it when it's written like that doesn't translate back to the same nasal syllable I think it's meant to represent. Cool (archaic?) words.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the old-fashioned and upper-class register, **tush** fits:

> *tush* [interjection]
>
> ... used as an exclamation of impatience, disdain, contempt, etc.

[[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tush)]

- *Tush, that's nothing, my friend did it in 15.*

As these are at least really slang usages, another candidate is **hmmpf** / **hmmf** / ... (Wiktionary has the hmmpf variant):

> *Hmph* (also *hrmph* or *humph*) indicates displeasure or indignation [including {depending on tone} a dismissive, scornful, perhaps even sneering riposte].

[[DailyWritingTips](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/100-mostly-small-but-expressive-interjections/#:%7E:text=Hmph%20(also%20hrmph%20or%20humph)%20indicates%20displeasure%20or%20indignation.)]

- Hmmpf, that's nothing: my friend did it in 15.

Comment: The SOED (1993) says "archaic".

Comment: As does [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/tush) for 'UK' _but not 'US'_ usage.

Comment: I suppose Collins ain't been in the US for some time now. The only usage I've ever heard for *tush* here is to refer to someone's derriere.

Comment: I suppose we just travel in different circles. But in my many decades of life here, I've never heard it used that way. The fact that is listed by AHD *first* is inconsequential if the usage is 1) archaic or 2) minuscule.

Comment: Well, then they failed either in their research or their presentation of it. I hope you will credit me with having a careful ear and a comprehensive mastery of my own language (including various dialects and multiple registers of it), and will believe me when I tell you I've never heard *tush* used that way in speech, writing, or film.

Comment: It's more like Ashworth's *ad hoc* citation, on which even the "experts" disagree, vs reality. Etymonline lists your version from the 15th century, in which period and location it would not sound ancient. The other dictionaries I consult give your version as archaic. Note that dictionaries differ on the way they order the definitions. Sometimes they give the oldest first, sometimes the most current. You should know that.

Comment: The OED cites Robert Louis Stevenson's usage of *tushery* to refer to "a conventional style of romance characterized by excessive use of affected archaisms such as 'tush!' ... and, given that Stevenson thought the term archaic and pretentious in the 19th century, I rest my case. The term *tush* is not a productive suggestion for current usage.

Comment: Your sarcasm convinces me that your argument was disingenuous all along.

Comment: Perhaps it is your cynicism that makes you see as sarcasm what is in fact an honest appraisal.

Comment: AHD list this usage also: They even list this sense first, without the 'archaic' caveat. M-W list it without an 'archaic' caveat.  I tried to average out 4 _archaics_ v 4 _unflagged_, as 'old-fashioned'. I've deleted unconstructive arguments; I'll leave it there. And no, I'd not use it, but neither would I use any interjections in this vein.

Answer (score 3):

## eh

is an expression I've read a number of times in books.

In person it would frequently be accompanied by a shoulder shrug and possible a one eyebrow raise.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can almost always interject an obscenity of the sexual or scatological kind, but since that's a given it's almost redundant to mention here.
2. You can simply say "but" to indicate that you are contradicting the claim of extrordinarity: "But that's nothing!" Of course that may not strictly count as an interjection.
3. You can say "why", which, as [Merriam-Webster notes under 4.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/why), is "used to express mild surprise, hesitation, approval, disapproval, or impatience", at least one of which should fit here: "Why, that's nothing, one of these newfangled auto-mobiles can make it easily in 10!" (Somehow I see the speaker in the England of the early 20th century...)

Comment: I'm always glad if anybody reads what I write, but I'm usually baffled when they don't agree ;-). What strikes you as wrong or inappropriate?